# Calculate the angle and long side of a parallelogram that is defined by a right triangle

Tags: trigonometry

Ok, so I need to calculate the angle and the length of long sides of a parallelogram that is defined my a right triangle. The top line of the parallelogram intersects the top corner (a) of the right triangle and the bottom line of the parallelogram intersects the bottom corner (b) of the right triangle. I also know the height of the parallelogram.

How can I accomplish this? I took Trig about 10 years ago and I've lost about 90% of it.

See image for details blue is what I need to know, black is what I do know.

(I did this in SolidWorks if you are wondering).
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Label the left side, bottom and hypotenuse of the triangle $a$, $b$ and $c$, respectively, and the unknown angle $\theta$. In addition, let the length of the short side of the parallelogram be $d$. We have the following relationships among the various lengths: $$a=c\cos\theta \\ b=c\sin\theta=12\frac78 \\d\sin\theta=1\frac12 \\ a+d=11\frac14$$ You thus have four equations in four unknowns, so it should be possible to work through them to find $c$ and $\theta$. To begin with, we have from the second and third equations $\frac23d=\frac8{103}c$, so one of those variables can be eliminated right away. Substituting for $a$ and $d$ in the last equation produces $$c\cos\theta+{12\over103}c=\frac{45}4.$$ From the second equation we have $\sin\theta={103\over8c}$, so the preceding equation becomes $$c\sqrt{1-\left({103\over8c}\right)^2}+{12\over103}c=\frac{45}4.$$ Solving this for $c$ is ugly, but straightforward. From the second equation at the top, $\theta=\arcsin{103\over8c}$, which you can look up or plug into a calculator once you have $c$.

Comment: d is not known, only the height is known. maybe cgiovanardi is correct and it is only solvable by approximation.

Comment: Yes, I know that $d$ is unknown, but neither are $a$ and $c$. The very first variable that I eliminate is in fact $d$. The last equation involves only $c$, the unknown long side length, which is what you’re looking for. There’s no guessing or trial-and-error fitting involved.

Comment: Oooooh *head slap* ok

Comment: Ok so why does 2/3 d = 8/103 c ? Getting lost there.

Comment: @TheColonel26 Rearrange the second and third equations into $\sin\theta=\dots$. Things that are equal to the same thing are equal to each other.

Answer (score 0):

We have the following two equations:

$$ 11.25 = \frac{1.5}{ sin( \color{blue}{53.89^{\circ}} ) }+ \color{red}{15.9375} \cdot cos( \color{blue}{53.89^{\circ}} ) $$

$$ (11.25 - \frac{1.5}{sin( \color{blue}{53.89^{\circ}} ) })^2 + 12.875^2 = \color{red}{15.9375}^2 $$

Comment: How do I find the 53.89 degree angle? My known values are 11.25, 12.875, and 1.5. I don't know the angle yet that is the first thing I need to find.

Comment: There is no easy way. Just trial and error, or numerical methods, till we find the desired results 15.9375 and 53.89924892... We can guess an angle, and in the first formula determine the red value. With this red value, in the second formula, confirm the angle. And so on.